# php outputs part of code without any echo

Tags: php, html

Here's my piece of code(full body code):

```
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function AddEvent(Syear, Smonth, Sday, Eyear, Emonth, Eday, hallNumber){
            ...
        }
    </script>
    <?php
        function GetMonthByCoding($first , $second , $third) {
            ...
        }

        function GetDateByCoding($coding){
            ...
        }

        function GetDateFromLine($line){
            ...
        }

        $userid = '...';
        $magicCookie = 'cookie';

        $feedURL = "...";
        $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

        foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
            $title = stripslashes($entry->title);
            if ($title == "HALL") {
                $summary = stripslashes($entry->summary);
                $date = GetDateFromLine($summary);
                echo ("<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'> AddEvent(" . $date['start']['year'] . ", " . $date['start']['month'] . ", " . $date['start']['day'] . ", " . $date['end']['year'] . ", " . $date['end']['month'] . ", " . $date['end']['day'] . "); </script>");
            }
        }
    ?>
  </body>
```

- `AddEvent()` is JavaScript function defined earlier.
  What I get in my browser is:

```
entry as $entry) { $title = stripslashes($entry->title); if ($title == "HALL") { $summary = stripslashes($entry->summary); $date = GetDateFromLine($summary); echo (""); } } ?>
```

Looks like it was an echo but as you can see there is no echo right in the middle of foreach.
Can anyone say what I am doing wrong?

Comment: We need to see more of the code before your loop before being able to spot the error

Comment: Add more code, i'm pretty sure it's a html comment issue

Comment: Is your server configured to handle PHP files?

Comment: You can remove `language='JavaScript'` since this attribute has been **deprecated** in favor of **type**

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not installed, or it is not enabled, or the file is not a `.php` file or the server has not been told to recognise it as a file to parse.

Try `View Source` and you should see all your PHP code. The only reason part of it shows up is because everything from `<?php` to the first `>` is considered by the browser to be an invalid tag.

Comment: Well my server worked fine with Zend Framework for like 4 months and now I try to make smth on simple php and I cant make it. In addition Opera doesnt show any of that, just Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: Opera probably parses the invalid HTML (since it's supposed to be PHP) differently from the other browsers. It's definitely a server issue - no PHP code should be shown to the browser at all.

Comment: Yeah. The view source stuff shows that php code is considered to be till `->` but usually it is till `?>`. So browser sees `-` as `?` and I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: Is the file a `.php` file?

Comment: It's not seeing `-` as `?`, it's seeing `>` as the match for `<`, to create one very long `<?php [...] ->` tag. The server is supposed to parse that before sending it to the browser.

Comment: Yes, that is `index.php` file.
@Brian Marshall Can you please tell me how to fix this problem, I dont even know how it occured.

Comment: @JohnWilliam What server software are you using?

Comment: @Brian Marshall XAMPP Version 2.5

Comment: @JohnWilliam Are you accessing the page through your server (like `http://localhost/`) or by opening the file directly?

Comment: @Brian Marshall I set the folder in vhosts file so it looks for index.php file. So in my browser I write http://site_name/ and it refers to this index.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was in the name of variable sxml. I renamed it and the problem escaped.